# Calculating Normals across a sphere with a wave-like vertex shader

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, 3d

This is a bit of a CS question, but more than not it's a 3D math problem.

I've been trying to get the correct normals for a sphere I'm messing with using a vertex shader. The algorithm can be boiled down simply to

vert.xyz += max(0, sin(time + 0.004*vert.x))*10*normal.xyz

This causes a wave to roll across the sphere.
In order to make my normals correct, I need to transform them as well. I can take the tangent vector at a given x,y,z, get a perpendicular vector (0, -vert.z, vert.y), and then cross the tangent with the perp vector.

I've been having some issue with the math though, and it's become a personal vendetta at this point. I've solved for the derivative hundreds of times but I keep getting it incorrect. How can I get the tangent? 
Breaking down the above line, I can make a math function

f(x,y,z) = max(0, sin(time + 0.004*x))*10*Norm(x,y,z) + (x,y,z)

where Norm(..) is Normalize((x,y,z) - CenterOfSphere)

[After applying f(x,y,z), unchanged normals](http://prntscr.com/5zkpw4)

What is the correct f '(x,y,z)?

I've accounted for the weirdness caused by the max in f(...), so that's not the issue.

Edit: The most successful algorithm I have right now is as follows:

Tangent vector.x = 0.004*10*cos(0.004*vert.x + time)*norm.x + 10*sin(0.004*vert.x + time) + 1

Tangent vector.y = 10*sin(0.004*vert.x + time) + 1

Tangent vector.z = 10*sin(0.004*vert.x + time) + 1

2nd Tangent vector.x = 0

2nd Tangent vector.y = -norm.z

2nd Tangent vector.z = norm.y

Normalize both, and perform Cross(Tangent2, Tangent1). Normalize again, and done (it should be Cross(Tangent1, Tangent2), but this seems to have better results... more hints of an issue in my math!).

This yields [this](http://prntscr.com/5zm1v3)